# Is a function continuous on a closed interval and positive at every rational positive everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis

"If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and if $f(x)$ is positive for each rational $x$, then does it follow that f is positive at all $x$?"

I'm not sure if I'm missing something major here. My textbook tells me that while $f$ can be zero at certain points, it must be nonnegative everywhere. That makes no sense to me.

Can't we define a piecewise function like $$f(x) = \begin{cases}x + 1&x\in[0,1]\\|x|&x\in\mathbb Q\setminus[0,1]\\-|x|&x\notin[0,1]\cup\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

Such a function would indeed be continuous on the interval $[0,1]$, would be positive for every rational, and would be negative at an infinite number of points.

Comment: I think they mean non-negative on $[0,1]$.

Comment: That's the quickest I've ever gotten a comment on a question! Thanks for the response. Why would f being nonnegative on [0,1] instead of continuous help the argument that f must be nonnegative everywhere?

Comment: No, I mean being continuous implies non-negative on $f([0,1])$.

Comment: Presumably, the function is only defined on $[0,1]$; that is, the function is positive at each rational in $[0,1]$.  Under that assumption, must $f$ be nonnegative for all $x$ in $[0,1]$?

Comment: This is the answer that my textbook gives: "Certainly f is nonnegative at all x. But the function $f(x) = (x − \sqrt{2})^2$ is positive for all rational x and equal to zero at $x = \sqrt{2}$ "

Comment: Observe that $x = \sqrt{2}$ means x can be outside of [0,1], which is why I'm so confused lol

Comment: Probably just a mistake. Note that the interval $[0,1]$ is not really significant here. Change the interval to $[0,2]$ and the solution makes sense.

Comment: @ElliotG That makes sense to me. Thanks everyone for clearing that up. I just wanted to know if I was going insane or not; good to hear I'm not.

Comment: No it's good to check these details (without driving yourself too crazy). Sometimes a single point matters a lot in analysis, especially in one-dimension

Comment: " Change the interval to [0,2] and the solution makes sense." Or change the function to $f(x) =(x - \frac 1{\sqrt 2})^2$ so $f(\frac 1{\sqrt 2})=0$

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in [0,1]$ then there exist rationals numbers $r_n$ converging to $x$. By continuity $f(x)=\lim f(r_n)$ and $f(r_n) >0$ for  all $n$. Hence $f(x) \geq 0$. The book is right and your example is not valid. Your function is not continuous.